# *char conversion to/from bool in call to strstr

Tags: c++

I have code that is supposed to remove all characters in one C-string from another.

The problem arises when I try to use the function `strstr`: both an array and a `char*` get converted to `bool`. Obviously it doesn't work because `strstr` needs to receive 2 `char*` arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

using namespace std;

char* temp_char(char* orig,char* del) 
{            char *str_temp, *temp, *p, *c;
            char symbol[2];
            int i=0;
            int len = strlen(orig);
            temp=(char *)calloc(len,1);
            str_temp = (char *)calloc(len,1);
            strcpy(str_temp,orig);
            
            for(i=0;i<strlen(del);i++){                
                symbol[0]=del[i];
                symbol[1]=0;
                temp[0]=0;
                 while( p=strstr(str_temp,del)!=NULL){
                  strncat(temp,str_temp,p-str_temp);
                  p++;
                    str_temp=p;
                 }
             strcat(temp,str_temp);    
            strcpy(str_temp,temp);     
            }
                cout<<temp;
    return temp;
}
int main () {
char a[]="stuccsess",b[]="test";
 
 temp_char(a,b);}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors in one line of your code. The first is not addressing the issue that the `!=` operator has higher priority than `=`. Thus, in the following line:

```cpp
while( p=strstr(str_temp,del)!=NULL) {
```

the comparison is actually:

```cpp
while( p = ( strstr(str_temp,del)!=NULL ) ){
```

So, you are attempting to assign the result of the `!=` test, which will be a `bool` value, to a `char*` variable (`p`).

You can fix this, easily, by putting the assignment expression in parentheses.

However, although that will fix the compiler error, it will not address the second error. Just a few lines above that `while` statement, you assign one of the characters of the `del` string to the first of the `symbol` string (and, properly, add a `nul` terminator to that) … but you never then actually ***use*** that `symbol` string. Instead, you pass the *entire* `del` string as the second argument in the call to `strstr`. You *should* be passing your created `symbol` as that second argument.

So, changing that `while` line to the following will make the code work:

```cpp
while ((p = strstr(str_temp, symbol)) != nullptr) { // Use nullptr in C++
```

But that leaves other errors in your function. How will you ever be able to free the memory allocated in the `str_temp = (char*)calloc(len, 1);` call? Once you have subsequently modified that `str_temp` pointer (in the `str_temp = p;` line), you no longer have the original pointer value, which must be used when calling `free()`. So, you need to save that value, just after you have made the allocation. (The `temp` memory pointer is returned, so that can be freed in the `main` function.)

There are other issues in your code that could be improved, like using `new[]` and `delete[]` in C++, rather than the old, C-language `calloc`, and that your index and length variables should really be of `size_t` type, rather than `int`. Here's a version with the corrections and suggestions discussed applied:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using std::cout;

char* temp_char(char* orig, char* del)
{
    size_t len = strlen(orig);
    char* temp = new char[len + 1];
    char* str_temp = new char[len + 1];
    char* save_temp = temp; // Save it so we can call delete...
    strcpy(str_temp, orig);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(del); i++) {
        char symbol[2];
        symbol[0] = del[i];
        symbol[1] = 0;
        temp[0] = 0;
        char* p;
        while ((p = strstr(str_temp, symbol)) != nullptr) {
            strncat(temp, str_temp, static_cast<size_t>(p - str_temp));
            p++;
            str_temp = p;
        }
        strcat(temp, str_temp);
        strcpy(str_temp, temp);
    }
    cout << temp;
    delete[] save_temp; // ... don't forget to free this.
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    char a[] = "stuccsess", b[] = "test";
    char* answer = temp_char(a, b);
    delete[] answer; // We should free the memory allocated!
    return 0;
}
```

But your approach is far more complicated than it need be. You can simply loop through the original string and check each character to see if it is in the 'delete' string (using the `strchr` function, for example); if it is not (i.e. that `strchr` returns `nullptr`), then append the character to the accumulated `temp` and increase the running length:

```cpp
char* temp_char(char* orig, char* del)
{
    size_t len = strlen(orig);
    char* temp = new char[len + 1];
    int newlen = 0;
    for (char* cp = orig; *cp != '\0'; ++cp) {
        if (strchr(del, *cp) == nullptr) temp[newlen++] = *cp;
    }
    temp[newlen] = '\0'; // Add null terminator
    std::cout << temp;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: THank you so much, i frigin love you.